# How to calculate difference between first and last score

Tags: r

I want to calculate the difference between the first and last score for each person according to the dates. Original data looks like this:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4)
Score <- c(3,2,1,1,2,0,0,3,4,0)
Date <- c("2020/01/01","2020/01/02","2020/01/03","2020/02/05","2020/02/06","2021/10/01","2021/10/02","2021/10/03","2021/10/04","2022/03/01")

a <- data.frame(ID,Score,Date)
```

desired dataset:

```
diff_first_last <- c(-2,-2,-2,1,1,4,4,4,4,0)
b <- data.frame(ID,Score,Date,diff_first_last)
```

Is there a way to do this easily because I want to apply it to a much bigger dataset.
I would appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is one possible dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
# build groupings by ID
dplyr::group_by(a, ID) %>%
    # convert date from text to date to be able to order by it
    dplyr::mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date)) %>% 
    # order by date just to be sure
    dplyr::arrange(Date) %>%
    # calculate first last diference 
    mutate(diff_first_last = dplyr::last(Score) - dplyr::first(Score)) %>%
    # ungroup to prevent unwanted behaviour downstream
    dplyr::ungroup()

 # A tibble: 10 x 4
      ID Score Date       diff_first_last
   <dbl> <dbl> <date>               <dbl>
 1     1     3 2020-01-01              -2
 2     1     2 2020-01-02              -2
 3     1     1 2020-01-03              -2
 4     2     1 2020-02-05               1
 5     2     2 2020-02-06               1
 6     3     0 2021-10-01               4
 7     3     0 2021-10-02               4
 8     3     3 2021-10-03               4
 9     3     4 2021-10-04               4
10     4     0 2022-03-01               0
```

EDIT: as @GKi pointed out the code is slow - the critical optimization would be to change lubridate::ymd() to as.Date() ... putting it through the test of larger data sets by varring the group size but keeping the number of unique observatiosn more or less the same we observe the following performance (dplyr solution performs better on large groups):

```
myfun <- function(dys, rps, edt) {
    # set up dummy data
    ID <- sort(rep(1:rps, dys))
    Score <- sample(0:99, dys, replace = TRUE)
    Date <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2021-01-01"), to = as.Date(edt), by = "days")
    a <- data.frame(ID, Score, Date)
    # shuffle the dummy data
    a <- a[sample(1:nrow(a)), ]
    # show number of unique values
    print(nrow(unique(a)))
    # use supplied benchmark function with the critical twist 
    bench::mark(check=FALSE,
    DPH = {dplyr::group_by(a, ID) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% # critical change of lubridate::ymd) to as.Date()
        dplyr::arrange(Date) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(diff_first_last = dplyr::last(Score) - dplyr::first(Score)) %>%
        dplyr::ungroup()},
    GKi = {. <- a[order(as.Date(a$Date)),]
      cbind(., diff_first_last = ave(.$Score, .$ID, FUN = \(x) x[length(x)] - x[1]))
      }
    )
}


 myfun(15, 6400, "2021-01-15")
[1] 96000
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory               time           gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>               <list>         <list>          
1 DPH           229ms    229ms      4.37    9.42MB     4.37     1     1      229ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [856 x 3]> <bench_tm [2]> <tibble [2 x 3]>
2 GKi           143ms    153ms      6.58   13.99MB     0        4     0      608ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [218 x 3]> <bench_tm [4]> <tibble [4 x 3]>

 myfun(46, 2400, "2021-02-15")
[1] 110400
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                  time           gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                  <list>         <list>          
1 DPH           108ms    111ms      9.09    12.8MB     3.03     3     1      330ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [12,127 x 3]> <bench_tm [4]> <tibble [4 x 3]>
2 GKi           175ms    181ms      5.48      16MB     0        3     0      548ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [4,838 x 3]>  <bench_tm [3]> <tibble [3 x 3]>

 myfun(90, 1200, "2021-03-31")
[1] 108000
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                 time           gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                 <list>         <list>          
1 DPH          67.8ms   69.9ms     14.2     11.8MB     2.36     6     1      423ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [6,127 x 3]> <bench_tm [7]> <tibble [7 x 3]>
2 GKi         166.9ms  171.1ms      5.82    15.5MB     0        3     0      516ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [2,438 x 3]> <bench_tm [3]> <tibble [3 x 3]>

 myfun(181, 600, "2021-06-30")
[1] 108600
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                 time           gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                 <list>         <list>          
1 DPH          50.2ms   52.9ms     16.9     11.5MB     2.42     7     1      413ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [3,131 x 3]> <bench_tm [8]> <tibble [8 x 3]>
2 GKi         172.8ms  175.2ms      5.66    15.5MB     0        3     0      530ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [1,238 x 3]> <bench_tm [3]> <tibble [3 x 3]>

 myfun(365, 300, "2021-12-31")
[1] 109500
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                 time            gc               
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                 <list>          <list>           
1 DPH            39ms   47.1ms     19.9     11.4MB     2.21     9     1      452ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [1,634 x 3]> <bench_tm [10]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
2 GKi           171ms    183ms      5.48    15.5MB     0        3     0      547ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [649 x 3]>   <bench_tm [3]>  <tibble [3 x 3]> 

 myfun(730, 150, "2022-12-31")
[1] 109500
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory               time           gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>               <list>         <list>          
1 DPH            33ms     35ms     26.5     11.3MB     4.41     6     1      227ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [884 x 3]> <bench_tm [7]> <tibble [7 x 3]>
2 GKi           164ms    165ms      5.94    15.5MB     0        3     0      505ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [345 x 3]> <bench_tm [3]> <tibble [3 x 3]>
```

Answer (score 6):

In *base* you can use `ave` assuming it is sorted by dates.

```
ave(a$Score, a$ID, FUN = \(x) x[length(x)] - x[1])
# [1] -2 -2 -2  1  1  4  4  4  4  0
```

In case it is not sorted.

```
a <- a[order(as.Date(a$Date)),]
```

---

Benchmark

```
set.seed(42)
a <- data.frame(ID = sample(0:9999, 1e5, TRUE), Score = sample(0:5, 1e5, TRUE),
      Date = c("2020/01/01","2020/01/02","2020/01/03","2020/02/05","2020/02/06",
           "2021/10/01","2021/10/02","2021/10/03","2021/10/04","2022/03/01"))

library(dplyr)
bench::mark(check=FALSE,
DPH = {dplyr::group_by(a, ID) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date)) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(Date) %>%
    mutate(diff_first_last = dplyr::last(Score) - dplyr::first(Score)) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()},
DPH2 = {dplyr::group_by(a, ID) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(Date) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(diff_first_last = dplyr::last(Score) - dplyr::first(Score)) %>%
     dplyr::ungroup()},
GKi = {. <- a[order(as.Date(a$Date)),]
  cbind(., diff_first_last = ave(.$Score, .$ID, FUN = \(x) x[length(x)] - x[1]))
  }
)
#  expres…¹      min   median itr/s…² mem_a…³ gc/se…⁴ n_itr  n_gc total_…⁵ result
#  <bch:ex> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:tm> <list>
#1 DPH        18.91s   18.91s  0.0529 137.6MB    2.33     1    44   18.91s <NULL>
#2 DPH2        1.37s    1.37s  0.732   11.5MB    3.66     1     5    1.37s <NULL>
#3 GKi      325.96ms 326.36ms  3.06    25.8MB    0        2     0 652.73ms <NULL>
```

The *base* solution is in this case about 4 times faster but uses double of memory compared with DPH2.

Comment: Nice I always like to highlight when there is a trivial or, at least, a short and comprehensive way to solve the problem in Base-R. For efficiency and maintenance. And that too is a nice workaround. It wouldn't occur to me to use ave() in that way

Comment: this is a very nice/fast solution for small sized data sets. Now if you scale the number of rows up, i.e. rep each vector by 10.000, your solution is aprox. 10 slower and uses more memory space... if we take one order of magnitude higher the results are worse

Comment: @DPH I have updated the answer, and increased the dataset for the benchmark but can not confirm this observations. Here still base is faster and used less memory.

Comment: very interesting, the way you set up the dummy data makes a massive diference (ID in increasing order), try ID = rep(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4), 10000) instead of ID = rep(1:9999, each=10)

Comment: In your case are only the 10 original rows, after running a `unique`, what can be used to increase speed and use less memory...

Comment: the main slowdown in my code is the lubridate::ymd(), replacing this with as.Date() and playing arround with some sample data with no repetition, varying only by group size, it seems as if the dplyr aproach without lubridate scales better for larger groups (I edited my answer with according code - possibly I commited an error though)

Comment: I still can not confirm this. Maybe because your dataset has the column Date in `Date` and not as `character`? But now the difference is very small and in memory usage its now better.